# What can be the approaches to merge (ensemble) a NON-Probabilistic model with RandomForest?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a `RF` for Text classification and it gives me accuracy. Almost same metric is given by another model built using `ElasticSearch` and it gives you a score, which you can not relate to. For example, For sample **X** it gave me 4 prediction results with some scores as `A 10,B 9,C 8,D 7` (for each prediction as pred1, pred2, pred3...) and for **Y**, it gave me `B 4,A 3,D 2,C 1` and for **Z**, it gave me `C 90,A 65,B 43,D 20`. You simply can not say if scores of sample **X** is better than **Y** or vice versa.  **But you can definitely say that `pred1` is better than `pred2` is better than `pred3`....**

What I observed is that my `RandomForest` gave better results for some `N` classes and the other model gave better results for `P` classes. When I compared the cumulative accuracy, it was say 95% but alone for any of the approach, it was 85%.

Is there any way where I can merge these two approaches? Suppose I make `One-Hot` encoded Class ids  (Vector of `N classes * 4 (results)`   + metadata / extra features from data) of all the Five results returned by the Elastic Algo and then use them in Logistic Regression with `Voting Classifier` of this and my `Random Forest`?? Just thinking out loud.

For example, let us suppose in a 4 class classification, if the model returned [A,B,C,D]as classes (in ORDER means A is better than B > C > D Total 4 classes), feature for that sample would be
[`00` `01` `10` `11`], I would pass it to a logistic Regression model and maybe use Voting Classifier along with my `RF`!! ?? Any good suggestions and approaches?

Comment: Can you shed any light onto the meaning of the scores that your ElasticSearch model returns? Without knowing anything about those scores (e.g. why they have such varying scale) it's difficult to answer your question. But in general, you could softmax the ElasticSearch scores to put them on the same scale as the RF scores.

Comment: Makes Sense. `Softmax-ing` the scores could give some info. So I just multiply the probabilities for both the models directly, right? Also, it is internal to Elastic only.I have no idea what is uses but I think it uses `BM25` for searching. Maybe it is related to that score. I aske dthe developer and he said that you can **can not** establish relation between scores of two different samples